# Transition after animation with @keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a loading indicator (a bar that continuously animates its width from 0% to 100%) using css3 keyframes. I trigger this behavior by adding a `.loading` class to by loading bar. Now once I am done loading I would like to animate *out of* the keyframes. Say, for example at the time that I finish loading the width is animated to 50% I would not have it jump to 100%, but ease it to 100% where it should stay.

I have tried adding a `transition` and `animation` to my loading bar class, but neither seems to be working. How do I go about this?

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/kYnhF/2/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `animationiteration` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/animationiteration)) event to detect when the animation reaches the end of a loop and then remove the class.

```
$('#bar').on('webkitAnimationIteration', function(e){
    $('#bar').removeClass('loading').off('webkitAnimationIteration');
});
```

**I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jedidiah/kYnhF/6/**

-

For simplicity I've only added the webkit prefix to the the fiddle but there is a useful article about css animation events in javascript here http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/ where they share a little function to simplify using the prefixes you could use to support other browsers.

Comment: Thanks - this is not a bad solution. However, is it possible to use a different transition to transition out of the current state? I basically want to simply 'fill up' the progress bar from where it is now, not complete the whole cycle (if possible)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, that's a bit trickier, especially since it either needs to fill out to the left or right depending how far through the animation it is, and then it may be a bit odd that it is suddenly going backwards. I guess you could try and work something out with AnimationEvent.elapsedTime (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent.elapsedTime)

Comment: Hm I see - you're right it might be a bit odd. Is there a way to speed up the transition to finish it quicker? The problem now is that one cycle takes too long and it feels unresponsive if the progress bar is still 'loading' for a while after the actual loading has taken place.

Comment: I'm not sure I imagine it would just jump back to the start of the animation if you switched to a faster one. It doesn't really answer the question but I suppose you could cheat and add a second bar that overtakes the first http://jsfiddle.net/jedidiah/kYnhF/9/

Comment: I see. That seems like a reasonable workaround. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to help :) Just read an interesting article that suggest you might be able to do what you are wanting at http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/ specifically the section "Manipulating CSS Animations"

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted @Jedidiah answer, I think that is what you need.

BTW, If you are interested in an alternative, simple CSS3 solution, then add to your `#bar`:

```
transition: all 1s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s
```

<kbd>[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ugBQN/)</kbd>

*Potential* drawbacks (depending on your needs):

1. It won't respect the previous speed of the progressbar (no matter if you are at 10% or 90%, the remaining part will take 1 second to complete... but this is how often the progressbars of the installers work, so it may not be a problem);
2. It won't run all the animation: if you are in the first half, it will fill to the left, instead of completing all the round.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be doing anything for me..?

Comment: Wow... I coded it on FF, now opening it in Chrome it does not work :| ... the idea behind is  **transition to all the default properties in one seconds**, starting from `left: 0` and `width: 100%;` if it is at `width: 30%` when you remove the `.loading` class, it will take 1 seconds to return to 100% (default of `#bar`). Strange it doesn't work on Chrome :/

Comment: This was exactly my first thought too, was surprised it didn't work, feels like it should.